# Are filters available for Blockchain.com APIs?

Tags: api, block

I'm trying to get the block details of Bitcoin using block height. The API provided on the "blockchain.com" website also dumps the huge transaction list along with the response. Is there a way to filter it at the server side? Or, are there any other services that give such APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Blockcypher.com](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#block-hash-endpoint)'s Block hash endpoint

Here is a sample api call
[Click here](http://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/blocks/00000000000000000003dc20b868d17121303308f6bba329302e75913f0790db?limit=-1)
It limits the transactions array to 1 element

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hal Streams.](https://www.hal.xyz/products/hal-stream) You can filter it server-side before getting the data exposed via API.